# How many copies will this code perform?

Tags: c++

(From an interview) How many copies of struct A might be performed when function DoSomething is called? If the number of copies is variable, how does it depend on the factors affecting it?

```
struct A
{
    int data[256];
};

A DoSomething(A a)
{
    A b = a;
    b.data[rand()%256] = 1;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [**How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**]  At least leave us with a **[MCVE]** that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: 1 copy with pre-C++11, 2 with C++11.

Comment: None as it is not runable.

Comment: Are you counting the copy made for when the struct is passed in to the function in the first place?  I think it would be 1) copy from caller to the function parameter, 2) assignment to anotherStupidStruct, and 3) for returning anotherStupidStruct.  But +1 to the comments about using a debugger to see.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How would you use a debugger to solve this problem? Please stop using that stock comment when it's not appropriate.

Comment: What do you think the answer is, and why? If you post your solution, we will help you understand why you're wrong.

Comment: @Barmar Using the debugger should clearly show how often the copy constructor is called, won't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Only for your compiler build with your code with your settings at this instant in time. This is implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, of course. Does that make the question more answerable?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a POD structure, it may not use the copy constructor and simply copy the data directly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I dont think it affects the answer, but it means that you can't learn anything accurate about the language by stepping through with the debugger.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear. And I think answers should give valid ranges and explain why the number of copies can varies and how much.

Comment: This question is not unclear.  This question cannot be solved with a debugger: what the compiler does in a particular instance does not describe what the range of permitted actions by a compiler under the C++ language.  @πάνταῥεῖ this is a misuse of your stock comment.  It is a non-ideal question for two reasons: one, it is copy-pasted from an interview question (which is not ideal, but not **bad**), and two it is not a *practical* problem that needs solving (but it isn't completely impractical either).

Comment: @Yakk _"This question cannot be solved with a debugger"_ I probably voted to close for a missing MCVE. It's not a very useful question though, isn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You voted to close based on a `int main() { auto x = DoSomething(); }` not being there?  The code posted is sufficient for a [MCVE].  The fact that two different call syntaxes can cause a different number of copies is actually useful information, and until you know the answer you could not practically know that, so one fixed call would actually make the question less interesting.  It may well be a duplicate of another question, or otherwise not be a good question, but it has a MCVE, it is clear, and the answer may surprise many.

Comment: @Yakk I mainly voted to close that question as ***being not useful for future research*** most probably. That's not a stock close vote reason though.

Answer (score -2):

3 copies

1. Passing argument, copies value
2. Creating new struct object
3. Returning from function

Gcc has an optimization called *Return Value Optimization* which prevents 3rd copy constructor to be invoked.

Gcc also flag *-fno-elide-constructors* which disable that optimization and copy constructor invokes in all cases

Comment: *return* could not invoke the copy-constructor. [Example](http://ideone.com/4aR5av). Note that is C++98

Comment: @Biagio, it actually does. Twice, in fact.  But the compiler is allowed to remove the copy constructor calls, even if they have side effects as in your example (see return value optimization).  So a test program proves nothing.

Comment: @SRobertz Exact! Because of RVO the copy 'ctor is not called or maybe not. The answer is not correct

Comment: *"Passing argument, copies value"* Maybe, maybe not. *"Creating new struct object"* Maybe, maybe not. *"Returning from function"*  Maybe, maybe not. Also, as copying the struct has no side effects, the compiler would be allowed to add more copies if it wants to (unlikely, yes). So the answer is "at least 0", which is not very useful.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, that should be the answer. And as the question was "how many copies *might* be performed, it is quite useful. And I guess knowing that there is no single answer is the main point.